# Javascript + Pubnub Chat Notifications

Tags: javascript, chat, pubnub

I am trying to make a sound when the user submits a chat, it will also be heard on the other person's end. Here is my code:

```
Enter Chat and press enter

<div><input id=input placeholder=you-chat-here /></div>
<code>Chat Output</code>
<div id=box></div>
<div id=pubnub pub-key=demo sub-key=demo></div>
<script src=http://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub-3.1.min.js></script>
<script>(function(){
    var box = PUBNUB.$('box'), input = PUBNUB.$('input'), channel = 'chatlllll';
        PUBNUB.subscribe({
            channel : channel,
            callback : function(text) { 
                box.innerHTML = 
                  (''+text).replace( /[<>]/g, '' ) + '<br>' +      box.innerHTML; 
            }
        });
    PUBNUB.bind( 'keyup', input, function(e) {
       (e.keyCode || e.charCode) === 13 && PUBNUB.publish({
           playsound('http://www.aphpsite.comuv.com/sound/chat.wav')
           channel : channel, 
           message : input.value, 
           x : (input.value='')
       });
   });
})();</script>
```

This is what I have. I am having trouble adding the sound. This script is broken. So none of this works. I would like if someone could fix it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking about PubNub and a Sample Chat Application with Sound Effect on Chat Message Arrival/Send.  I've updated the example and provided an extra **sound.js** JavaScript HTML5 lib that will help with playing the sound effect.  Note that I took your Sound **WAV** file and converted it to **OGG** and **MP3** file formats as well in order to provide cross browser compatibility.  Next I will paste the Complete and Working Source Code for the Chat with Sound Effects on Receiving of a message.  Following the source code, I have pasted the URL Resources that you need such as **sound.js** and the **audio** files too.

Try it **LIVE!** - http://pubnub-demo.s3.amazonaws.com/chat-with-sounds/chat.html

See Source Code:

```
<div><input id=input placeholder=chat-here></div>
<code>Chat Output</code>
<div id=box></div>
<div id=pubnub pub-key=demo sub-key=demo></div>
<script src=http://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub-3.1.min.js></script>
<script src=sound.js></script>
<script>(function(){
    var box = PUBNUB.$('box'), input = PUBNUB.$('input'), channel = 'chatlllll';
    PUBNUB.subscribe({
        channel : channel,
        callback : function(text) { 
            // PLAY SOUND HERE
            sounds.play('chat');

            // UPDATE TEXT OUTPUT HERE
            box.innerHTML = 
                (''+text).replace( /[<>]/g, '' ) +
                '<br>' +
                box.innerHTML; 
        }
    });
    PUBNUB.bind( 'keyup', input, function(e) {

       (e.keyCode || e.charCode) === 13 && PUBNUB.publish({
           channel : channel, 
           message : input.value, 
           x       : (input.value='')
       });
   });
})();</script>
```

**Download Source Code on GitHub**

https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-api/tree/master/app-showcase/chat-with-sounds - Click link to visit the PubNub GitHub Repository with Source Code for the Chat with Sound Demo.